# AdapterHandler - abstract class Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I have onClickListener in my Custom Adapter for ListView

```
 holder.name.setText(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_name());

    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(adapterhandler !=null) {
                adapterhandler.updateText(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_name());
            }

            if(!mRadioManager.isPlaying()) {

                mRadioManager.connect();
                mRadioManager.startRadio(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_url());

            }
            else
            {
                mRadioManager.stopRadio();
            }

        }
    });
```

Then I made Abstract Class to update TextView

```
    public abstract class InterfaceUpdate
```

{
    public void updateText(String text) {}
}

and Listener in Fragment to update TextView:

```
 @Override
public void onRadioStarted() {

    adapter.adapterhandler = new InterfaceUpdate() {
        @Override
        public void updateText(String text) {

            super.updateText(text);
            title.setText(text);

        }
    };
```

What is my problem? I cannot make

adapterhandler.updateText(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_name());

without checking if it's null, because it's generate NullPointerException
when I click on list element first time, TextView is not changing, second time is changing perfect ...;/ Any idea how to not make this adapterhandler null?

Comment: why are you calling `super.updateText(text)`?  You know it does nothing.

Comment: it's just trash code, just deleted... problem is that I am calling this updateText when radio is playing but first time it's not playing ;)
seriously, I don't know where to put it, it should update to when element on list is clicked (TextView)
I cannot put it in onCreate, etc. because it will be null. Hmmm...

For now when I click first time, there is nothing to do, TextView is not updated. Click second time, handler and text is not null, radio is playing, so it's changing correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your adapterhandler is not being created until after the first time you try and call updateText.  (It's not called until the onRadioStarted() callback is called by `mRadioManager.startRadio`)

Try this (although constructing your handler in onClick is not a great design)

```
holder.name.setText(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_name());

final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (null == adapterhandler) {
            adapterhandler = new InterfaceUpdate() {
                @Override
                public void updateText(String text) {
                    title.setText(text);
                }
            }
        }
        adapterhandler.updateText(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_name());
        if(!mRadioManager.isPlaying()) {
            mRadioManager.connect();
        } else {
            mRadioManager.stopRadio();
        }
    }
});
```

And change your onRadioStarted:

```
@Override
public void onRadioStarted() {
     mRadioManager.startRadio(dataModelList.get(position).getRadio_url());
};
```